# No puedo efectuar bien la recursión en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo este ejercicio, ya pude concluir true o false para los objetos del primer nivel, pero los objetos anidados debo utilizar la recursión para que me diga si dentro de esos

```
//   - Un objeto anidado es un objeto que dentro tiene uno o más objetos.
//     Ej:
//        const user = {
//            id: 6,
//            email: 'homero@maxpower.com',
//            infoPersonal: {
//                nombre: 'Homero Simpson',
//                direccion: {
//                    calle: 'Avenida Siempreviva',
//                    numero: 742,
//                    barrio: 'Springfield',
//                    estado: 'Massachusetts'
//                }
//            }
//        }
//   - Caso que devuelve true  --> objContains(user, "barrio", "Springfield");
//   - Caso que devuelve false --> objContains(user, "empleo", "Empleado en planta nuclear");
// Pista: utilizar typeof para determinar si el valor de una propiedad es un objeto para aplicar
// allí la recursión
```

este es mi codigo pero no sé por qué no me paso el text, la idea es que me siga con la recursión dicendo si los valores que me pasaron estan o no estan. Seguro estoy aplicando mal la recursión o me falta un dato.

```
var objContains = function(obj, prop, value){

for (let prop in obj) {
      if (obj[prop] === value) return(true);
      if (obj[prop] !== value) return(false);
     if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object'){
       objContains(obj[prop]) ;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Es mas, podrías ahorrarte código terminando con un return (obj[prop]===value) en vez de con dos 'if' (que el segundo podría ser un else)
Por cierto, la opcion recursiva, no retorna el resultado, entiendo que que deberia ser return objContains(obj[prop])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La dificultad del ejercicio está en que el objeto puede contener la tupla <llave,valor> anidada dentro de otra propiedad, de manera que el true/false sobre las propiedades directas del objeto son el caso trivial. Entonces, iterando en las llaves del objeto

- entro al bucle

  - Si encuentro la llave y su valor es el buscado, retorno true
  - Si una propiedad es objeto, y la recursión me retorna true, retorno true
- después del bucle no se cumplió lo de arriba, retorno false

La recursión se seguirá llamando hasta dar con un objeto que no contenga más que valores escalares, e irá devolviendo false aguas arriba.

Me parece que no debe haber ningún `return false` en el bucle. Igual llegará a false por efault. Nótese que retornar true genera un corto circuito y deja de buscar.

```js
function contieneObj(objeto, llave, valor) {

  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(objeto)) {
    if (key === llave && value === valor) return true;
    if (typeof value === 'object' && contieneObj(value, llave, valor)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}


const user = {
  id: 6,
  
  email: 'homero@maxpower.com',
  infoPersonal: {
    nombre: 'Homero Simpson',
    esposa: 'Marge',
    amigos: ['Moe', 'Barney'],
    hijos: [{
      nombre: 'bart'
    }, {
      nombre: 'lisa'
    }, {
      nombre: 'maggie'
    }],
    direccion: {
      calle: 'Avenida Siempreviva',
      numero: 742,
      barrio: 'Springfield',
      estado: 'Massachusetts'
    }
  }
};

console.log('{barrio:Springfield}', contieneObj(user, 'barrio', 'Springfield'));
console.log('{nombre:lisa}', contieneObj(user, 'nombre', 'lisa'));
console.log('{id:5}', contieneObj(user, 'id', 5));
console.log('{amigos:"Barney"}', contieneObj(user, 'amigos', 'Barney'));
```

Hay casos de borde, por ejemplo en mi snippet dice que no tiene un amigo 'Barney', pero es eso correcto? En rigor el objeto sí tiene un amigo 'Barney', si bien no contiene la tupla {amigo: 'Barney'}.

Para ese caso habría que agregar un chequeo:

```
  if (value instanceof Array && value.includes[valor]) return true;
```

Tampoco contempla el caso en que busco por un objeto. `contieneObj(user, 'esposa', {nombre: 'Marge'})`

Usando el valor stringificado (en otro caso nunca serán iguales), se manejaría añadiendo:

```
  if (typeof value === 'object'
      && typeof valor === 'object' 
      && JSON.stringify(valor) === JSON.stringify(value)) return true;
```

Ambos casos de borde aplican sólo si además estamos parados en la key correspondiente a la llave. Entonces

```js
function contieneObj(objeto, llave, valor) {

  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(objeto)) {
    if (key === llave) {
      if(value === valor) return true;
      if(value instanceof Array && value.includes(valor)) return true ;    
      if (typeof value === 'object'
          && typeof valor === 'object' 
          && JSON.stringify(valor) === JSON.stringify(value)) return true;
    }
    if (typeof value === 'object' && contieneObj(value, llave, valor)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
 const user = {
      id: 6,
      
      email: 'homero@maxpower.com',
      infoPersonal: {
        nombre: 'Homero Simpson',
        esposa:{nombre:'Marge'},
        amigos: ['Moe', 'Barney'],
        hijos: [{
          nombre: 'bart'
        }, {
          nombre: 'lisa'
        }, {
          nombre: 'maggie'
        }],
        direccion: {
          calle: 'Avenida Siempreviva',
          numero: 742,
          barrio: 'Springfield',
          estado: 'Massachusetts'
        }
      }
    };
    
    console.log('{id:5}', contieneObj(user, 'id', 5));
    console.log('{amigos:"Barney"}', contieneObj(user, 'amigos', 'Barney'));
    console.log('{esposa:{nombre:"Marge"}}', contieneObj(user, 'esposa',{nombre:"Marge"}));
```

Ahí dejé fuera casos más elaborados como  `contieneObj(user,'hijos',{nombre:'lisa'})` o `contieneObj(user,'amigos',['Barney'])` que sería dar como true el caso donde un array contiene por completo a otro.

Si te fijas, estamos entrando al bucle y luego ejecutando unos IF anidados horribles sólo cuando hay coincidencia entre `llave` y `key`: es ineficiente entrar al bucle.

Por otro lado, se vuelve difícil para el observador entender qué se está comprobando en cada if. Para esto sería mejor usar el [patrón strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) que es más conciso y explicativo. Lo usamos fuera del bucle, el cual sirve únicamente para que, de no cumplirse ninguna estrategia, haga la recursión.

Con este patrón puedes comentar y descomentar las estrategias admisibles

```js
class Strategies {
  constructor(obj, llave) {
    this.obj = obj;
    this.llave = llave;
    this.valor = obj[llave];
  }
  igualdadEscalar(value) {
    return this.valor === value;
  }
  igualdadStringified(value) {
    return typeof value === 'object' &&
      typeof this.valor === 'object' &&
      JSON.stringify(this.valor) === JSON.stringify(value);
  }
  arrayIncluye(value) {
    return this.valor instanceof Array && this.valor.includes(value);
  }
  arrayStringified(value) {
    return this.valor instanceof Array &&
      this.valor.filter(item => JSON.stringify(value) === JSON.stringify(item)).length > 0;
  }

};

function contieneObj(objeto, llave, valor) {
  const strategies = new Strategies(objeto, llave);
  
  if (strategies.igualdadEscalar(valor)) return true;
  if (strategies.igualdadStringified(valor)) return true;
  if (strategies.arrayIncluye(valor)) return true;
  if (strategies.arrayStringified(valor)) return true;
  
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(objeto)) {
    if (typeof value === 'object' && contieneObj(value, llave, valor)) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
const user = {
  id: 6,

  email: 'homero@maxpower.com',
  infoPersonal: {
    nombre: 'Homero Simpson',
    esposa: {
      nombre: 'Marge'
    },
    amigos: ['Moe', 'Barney'],
    hijos: [{
      nombre: 'bart'
    }, {
      nombre: 'lisa'
    }, {
      nombre: 'maggie'
    }],
    direccion: {
      calle: 'Avenida Siempreviva',
      numero: 742,
      barrio: 'Springfield',
      estado: 'Massachusetts'
    }
  }
};
console.log("{barrio:'Springfield'}", contieneObj(user, 'barrio', 'Springfield'));

console.log("{email: 'homero@maxpower.com'}", contieneObj(user, 'email', 'homero@maxpower.com'));
console.log('{id:5}', contieneObj(user, 'id', 5));
console.log('{amigos:"Barney"}', contieneObj(user, 'amigos', 'Barney'));
console.log('{esposa:{nombre:"Marge"}}', contieneObj(user, 'esposa', {
  nombre: "Marge"
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

En tu código veo algunos detalles discutibles.

- La función tiene "prop" como parámetro que luego no usas (lo redefines).
- Dentro el bucle, hay dos if's en los que siempre se ejecutará uno de los dos, y como se resuelven con un return, la tercera línea nunca se ejecutará.
- Llamas a la función recursivamente, pero sin indicar que buscas ni usar el resultado para nada.

Un ejemplo del código podría ser parecido a este.

```js
// Entiendo que la funcion debe responder true/false, sin indicar en que posición.

var objContains = function(obj, value){
    var encontrado = false;
    for (let prop in obj) {
        if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') encontrado = objContains(obj[prop],value);
        else encontrado = obj[prop] === value;
    // Guarda el resultado en 'encontrado' y en caso de ser true, no hace falta seguir buscando y sale del bucle, sinó, devolveria el resultado de la última posición del objeto.
        if (encontrado) break;
    }
    return encontrado
 }

ejemplo={ a:1, b:2, c:{ca:1, cb:2, cc:{cca:1, ccb:2, ccc:3, ccd:4}, cd:3}, d:3};
console.log("Busca 0: ",objContains(ejemplo,0));
console.log("Busca 4: ",objContains(ejemplo,4));
```

Nota:

- Usar varios return en una función se considera una mala práctica (va a gustos, personalmente no me molesta, pero puede que a un profesor si, te aconsejo usar solo uno al final de la función).
- A este código le falta añadir un par de detalles para ser la respuesta a tu ejercicio, pero la idea es que lo hagas tu. Una pista, el "prop" que usas como parámetro es distinto al "prop" que usas en el bucle, debes incluirlo como parámetro con un nombre distinto al bucle y comprobar si el dato encontrado corresponde a la propiedad que buscas.